# How to Show and Hide UISearchDisplayController's UISearchBar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a button search that located in the right side of the navigation.
This is my code:

```
UIButton *btnSearch = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnSearch.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22);
[btnSearch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(showSearch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *searchItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:_btnSearch];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = searchItem ;
```

This is how it's look.
[image]

And I want to display search bar after clicked on the search button, and close it after clicked on cancel and then show the Navigationbar back, but I don't know how to code it.

```
- (IBAction)showSearch:(id)sender{
    ???
}
```

This what I want. 
[image]

Please help or provide some sample code. I really need it.

Thank for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a property `UISearchBar *mySearchBar` to your viewController as

`@property(nonatomic, retain) UISearchBar *mySearchBar;`

Conform to `UISearchBarDelegate` as

```
@interface HomeViewController () <UISearchBarDelegate>
...
...
@end
```

Then implement the `showSearch` method as

```
-(void)showSearch:(id)sender {
if(!mySearchBar) {
    mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    [mySearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 55)];
    [mySearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview: mySearchBar];
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}else {
    searchBar.alpha = 1.0;
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}
```

Then implement the search bar delegate method as :

```
 - (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar {
        self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
        [mySearchBar setAlpha:0.0];
    }
```

Hope you have got the idea by doing this. Also you can add it directly to navigation controller, itself, if you want & then play with Showing/ hiding the `searchBar` alone.

You can add it to navigation controller as just initialize the `mysearchBar` & add it to `navigationBar` as :

```
   UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:mySearchBar];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's work now.
But,,, how to make it become responder so that I don't have to click on the textbox search. What I mean is when user click on Search button in navigationbar then show mySearchbar with blinking cursor inside textbox search !!

Thank ^^

Comment: You have to tell the system that you want your search bar to be the first responder. So Just add this line to the code where ever you are showing your searchbar. In the above code, you can add it after if-else block. (or add it inside if as well as else block).

`[mySearchBar becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: Search cancel button is working good. when the cancel button was clicked it will hide search bar and then show Navigation bar back.
How to resign search bar by not clicking on cancel button? I mean even though user click on out side of textbox search like (result list).
Thank

Comment: There are many logical methods to do it. It is up to you which one you want. For example: you can call the cancel button logic when you touch the search result table or view. You can also have a hidden UIView with clear color & add a tap gesture to it, then on the tap of the hidden view you can call the same cancel button logic.