# NavigationItem + UISearchBar with Swift

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to add a UISearchBar to been called when I click on a Left Navigation Item in m Navigation Bar.

Just like this (Image 1) :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tF7.png

And after I click the button (Image 2)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWNCB.png

I've tried this way :

```
    @IBAction func searchController2(sender: AnyObject) {
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    definesPresentationContext = true
    }
```

But the problem is, when I click on my button, is created a search bar between my navigation bar and my tableview, I just want to call the effect of the image number 2 directly.

It's exactly what I want, but I don't know how to convert it to swift :

[How to Show and Hide UISearchDisplayController's UISearchBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592395/how-to-show-and-hide-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-uisearchbar)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UINavigationController, you can use the title view of the navigationItem.

`navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`