# Hide/Show SearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, searchbar

I am trying to show a hidden search bar using the following code.  What happens is the search bar does not at first appear.  As soon as I touch the screen, it redraws to show the searchBar but the searchBar is not appearing on its own.  The VC does conform to the UISearchBarDelegate pattern.

Can anyone suggest what could be problem?

```
- (void) showSearchBar {
if (_barMovedUp==YES) {
CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y -       self.searchBar.bounds.size.height;
self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
self.barMovedUp = NO;}
self.searchBar.hidden=NO;
self.searchShowing=YES;//keeps track of whether showing or not
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
}
```

Should I move the delegate line elsewhere?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Show and Hide UISearchDisplayController's UISearchBar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592395/how-to-show-and-hide-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-uisearchbar)

Comment: The link is interesting and wish it solved problem but it creates the search bar in code.  Mine is created in storyboard.  Can't see how I can fix my code using it.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the delegate assignment; moving that line is probably not necessary. In your storyboard, you have the top of the search bar aligned with the top of the table view and at the same level, but before the table view in the view hierarchy?

Comment: No the search bar is below the tableview.  I could not get it to be a subview of the view that contains the table view, in other words, moving the cursor around it would not take.  So I've ended up making it a subview of tableview.

Comment: It sounds like your view controller extends table view controller, and you are attaching the search bar as a subview to the view controller's table view. If that is the case, my best recommendation is to extend the base UIViewController instead of UITableViewController based on my own experience and other posts on SO. If you'd rather not do that, it would help if you post more info about the constraints between the table view and search bar.